Arducam can't open camera by index (V4L2)
I have a raspberry Pi 4 and I am using a arducam camera along with open Cv it was working fine until now and suddenly is shows error
"code
[WARN:0] global/tmp/pip-wheel-w_lllcn3/opencv-python_622962b8a47a42ed9a5e55c557dab@ed/opencv/modules/video10/src/cap v41.cpp (893) open VIDEOIO (V4L2:/dev/video0): can't open camera by index"
Everything is same i haven't changed the code, even the example code stoped working.
I tried
Import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(-1)

while True:

  success, frame = cap.read()

  cv2.imshow('win', frame)

  cv2.waitKey(1)

I also tried:
cv2.VideoCapture(0,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
cv2.VideoCapture(index, cv2.CAP_V4L)

But nothing works
Error message:
[ WARN:0] global/tmp/pip-wheel-w_lllcn3/opencv-python_622962b8a47a42ed9a5e55c557dab@ed/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap v41.cpp (893) open VIDEOID (V4L2:/dev/video0): can't open camera by index


Can you please correct the formatting of the code? Also, which error message are you getting?

@TinoD i changed the formatting and added the error

try some of the suggestions here

those devices only work with libcamera/libcamera2. they refuse to use standard V4L/V4L2 APIs. you can replicate the issue with any other program that would try to use V4L2, such as ffmpeg, VLC, guvcview...

@TinoD i tried it i got a list of 4 indexes that opened but none of them worked they gave timeout error

@ChristophRackwitz can you please explain more, the camera was working fine before it stopped working suddenly

@KevinDedhia see Christoph Rackwitz's comment

@TinoD I dont understand why the camera will stop working suddenly.

"suddenly"? what changed? -- the error message you posted wasn't a clean copy. it was either OCRed or typed manually.
